# OPenVPN - VPN keeps disconnecting ubuntu 20.04, wifi connection remains connected

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and it's a standalone machine there is no server to connect to. I have the GUI version available which was pre-installed when i purchased the computer. The openvpn "package" was also pre-installed. I have performed several steps including removing openvpn package and reinstalling the open vpn package.  I have the following package currently installed:

`sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn`

I am using vpnbook for my .ovpn files, specifically this one:

vpnbook-us1-udp53.ovpn

When using the GUI, the VPN would connect and then within 3-5 minutes it would disconnect automatically.  So I resorted to using the terminal.

`sudo openvpn --config vpnbook-us1-udp53.ovpn`

The connection did establish, but I noticed in the output that it would establish and then disconnect and reestablish.  The problem I have with this method is that I have to leave the terminal open.  I would like to be able use the GUI, establish the connection and do my work with the terminal closed.  I tried editing the following per another user's question:

`sudo vi /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

Uncommented the following line:

`prepend domain-name-servers 198.7.62.204, 198.7.58.147, 127.0.0.1;`

Then ran:
`sudo service network-manager restart`

This activated the wired connection.  I connect wirelessly to the network so this solution didn't work and I reverted the changes and restarted the service again.  If anyone has a peristent VPN established using OpenVPN service through a wifi internet connection I would appreciate some assistance.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use/Configure OpenVPN properly:

1. Download the OpenVPN .ovpn files from https://www.vpnbook.com/

example- `vpnbook-us1-tcp443.ovpn`

2. `cd /path/vpnbook-us1-tcp443.ovpn`  where "path" is the directory the file was downloaded into  - the default for me is `Downloads`
   THEN
   `scp` the files into /etc/openvpn

   `sudo scp vpnbook-us1-tcp443.ovpn /etc/openvpn`
3. run `sudo openvpn --config vpnbook-us1-tcp443.ovpn`

Note: The above command can be run from `etc/openvpn` OR any directory which contains the `vpnbook-xxx-xxx.ovpn` file.

4. input the OpenVPN username and password provided at https://www.vpnbook.com/
5. Leave the terminal open and the command running until you no longer need the VPN. Then `ctrl c` to return to the command prompt

Got my answer; this is just how Openvpn works. It's much more stable from the command line than the GUI.  I was using vpnbook.com vice surfshark, but it functions the same way. This is the source I'm citing as the answer to my question.

https://support.surfshark.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011051133-How-to-set-up-OpenVPN-using-Linux-Terminal

Comment: This is right. You have to pay a VPN service provider (**like surfshark**) and buy the service. Once you pay, you will create an userID and password in the VPN service provider's website. Then you will need to follow their instructions, such as download the `.ovpn` files from their site to be used with their service. You can't just randomly download an `.ovpn` file and use it with any service provider.